# React Native: Fetch requests are not working with remote debugger active (Android)

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, fetch

I am going through a weird issue with RN that doesn't seem to allow requests to work without the debugger active. The basic repro is try to fetch from an external API on Android without the debugger active. We aren't doing anything different from the examples given at all. No errors showing in the logs, in fact from the looks of it they work and we have the data but the app refuses to update redux for some reason. It basically soft locks but doesn't crash. If I can provide any better information let me know, I'm just unsure why I'm seeing this issue only on Android while iOS works totally fine.

Answer (score 2):

I should've come back to this to say I found an answer. Required on Android only but simply use this:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

It should work then. It was specific to the API and parsing some data coming through that wasn't being logged for whatever reason. We found it through crash data recovered on AppCenter.ms through CodePush.

Comment: where should we add this import statement?

Comment: okay I put the import statement in my Api File where I was using fetch to send API requests. It solved my problem. Quite unbelievable though. Thanks man